# Joined to creditmemo_flat_table

Tags: php, mysql, magento

When joined to `creditmemo_flat_table`

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_creditmemo_grid_collection');
$collection->getSelect()
            ->join(
                array('creditmemo_table' => 'sales_flat_creditmemo'),
                'main_table.entity_id = creditmemo_table.entity_id',
                array('creditmemo_table.gift_cards_amount')
            );
```

I got right value when `gift_cards_amount` exist and got **null** when it does not exist.
But for grid I need **zero** instead of **null**.
Does someone have some idea how to resolve that?

Comment: use render and check the value of element add return result what you want.

Comment: What do you want.tell me with details so that we can help you.Any issue on php level ?

Comment: I want that my collection has "zero" value instead of "Null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL select syntax provides IFNULL method, which can be used here directly.

So this is how you should modify your select statement

```
$collection->getSelect()
        ->join(
            array('creditmemo_table' => 'sales_flat_creditmemo'),
            'main_table.entity_id = creditmemo_table.entity_id',
            array('IFNULL(creditmemo_table.gift_cards_amount,0) as gift_cards_amount')
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by two ways mysql and magento way of renderer like this mysql way :

```
$collection->getSelect()
        ->join(
            array('creditmemo_table' => 'sales_flat_creditmemo'),
            'main_table.entity_id = creditmemo_table.entity_id',
            array('COALESCE(creditmemo_table.gift_cards_amount,0) as gift_cards_amount')
        );

    OR
```

Magento way 
you can set renderer for the field like this :

```
$this->addColumn('title', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('module')->__('Title'),
          'width'     => '250px',
          'align'     =>'left',
          'index'     => 'title',
          'renderer' => new Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_CheckNull(),
      ));
```

Create folder under Block->Adminhtml with name Renderer and file with name CheckNull.php.
   like    `Block->Adminhtml->Renderer->CheckNull.php`
   And in checknull page write down code like this :

```
   <?php

class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_CheckNull extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{

    public function render(Varien_Object $row) {
        if($row->getData('title')==Null)
        {
            return '0';
        }else{
            return $row->getData('title');
        }
    }

}
```